# Is there a work around for scanning and exporting a real world object with Hololens with all of it's texture details?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scanning, hololens

I'm about to develop something which is based on scanning real world objects. But however I could not find a way to scan the single object with texture. Is there a workaround. I've heard about Kinect will it work with Hololens?

Comment: This is way too broad. You need to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: This is still in planning all I want to know is there a way to do so. If yes what it is. The whole project depends on it.

Comment: Hololens does not do object detection (at least not yet). Vuforia could be a solution. It does image recognition and 3d object recognition, not sure the 3d part is already available in Hololens. The image part is definitely as we got it to work. This is all still beta dev.

Comment: That's not really what Stack Overflow is for. It isn't a forum and people here aren't going to do your research for you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion (: @Soviut

Comment: The question is "Can hololens do object recognition?" and is a technical question about whether or not Hololens is able to perform that action. The answer is not, but Vuforia can do it within Hololens. That is a technical answer that fits the SO requirement.

Comment: @Everts Thanks for the suggestion let me check it out.